# findFirst() no encuentra el valor deseado

Tags: java, java-stream

Estoy intentando usar el Api Stream y el resultado no es el esperado: no me devuelve el valor que necesito.

Lo que necesito es: si la posición del elemento del array es igual al parámetro *number*, traer ese valor de esa posición que coincide con el parámetro *number*.

```
private void metodo(Integer number){ //number = 6
    String checkDigitTable = "t,r,w,a,g,d";
    String[] listCheckDigits = checkDigitTable.split(",");

    String checkDigit = "";
    for (int n = 0; n <= listCheckDigits.length; n++) {
      if (n == number) {
        checkDigit = listCheckDigits[n - 1];
      }
    }
    System.out.println(checkDigit); => imprime d (es correcto)
}
```

***Código usando Api Stream***

```
List<String> list1 = Arrays.stream(checkDigitTable.split(",")).toList();
String check = IntStream.range(0, list.length+1).filter(s -> list1.indexOf(s) == number).findFirst().toString();
System.out.println(check); => Imprime OptionalInt.empty (deberia ser d)
```

Answer (score 1):

Tal vez te sirva hacer lo siguiente:

```
String AA = list1.stream()
          .filter( s -> list1.indexOf( s ) == number -1 )
          .findFirst()
          .get();
```

obtenemos el flujo con

```
list1.stream()
```

filtramos con:

```
.filter( s -> list1.indexOf( s ) == number -1 )
```

terminamos la búsqueda con el primer "match":

```
.findFirst()
```

y por último, obtenemos el dato con:

```
.get()
```

Comment: muchas gracias.

Comment: Un placer ayudarte!.